# Using regex to extract and reformat timestamp the only way?

Tags: java, regex, date, datetime, timestamp

I need to read a list of timestamps and sort them by **"oldest"** and **"newest"** order. But before I can sort them, I need to reformat them first. Those timestamps are in the following format:

***mm:hh PM/AM dd Month(e.g.Jun) yyyy***,

**For example:**

- **3:40 PM 1 Jun 2016**
- **11:40 AM 11 Jun 2016**

I am using Regex to extract and reformat each timestamp into a format that Java will recognize, e.g. ***dd Month(e.g. Jun) yyyy hh:mm***

What I have done is as following:

```
package regularExpressionDate;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class regularExpressionDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "^(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{1,2})\\s(PM|AM)\\s(\\d{1,2})\\s(\\w{3})\\s(\\d{4})$";
        String date1 = "3:40 PM 1 Jun 2016";
        String newDate1;
        int hour;

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m1 = r.matcher(date1);

        if(m1.find()) {
            hour = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(1));
            if(m1.group(3).equals("PM")) {
                hour+=12;
                System.out.println(m1.group(3));
            }
            newDate1 = (m1.group(4) + " " + m1.group(5) + " " + m1.group(6) + " " + hour + ":" + m1.group(2));
            System.out.println(newDate1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No match");
        }
    }
}
```

For input `3:40 PM 1 Jun 2016`, I got `1 Jun 2016 15:40`.

My question is:

- Is my approach the best way to achieve my goal in terms of clarity and efficiency? I was hoping there would a method that could convert into Java recognized timestamp format right away, but I did not find it.

Comment: Take a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Comment: @RC., thank you will do

Comment: You can sort the date as number after parsing them. You don't have to sort them as Strings.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, thanks, written your suggestion down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your date String to Java Date by using SimpleDateFormat

```
    String date = "3:40 PM 1 Jun 2016";

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a dd MMM yyyy");
    Date startDate = formatter.parse(date);
    System.out.println(startDate);
```

After this you can sort date objects using comparator.

Comment: thank you. voted up. This will be the answer to my question.

Comment: Glad that helped you, have fun coding :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Stream API to parse and sort multiple dates

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a d MMM yyyy");
List<LocalDateTime> dates =
        Stream.of("3:40 PM 1 Jun 2016", "11:40 AM 11 Jun 2016")
                .map(text -> LocalDateTime.parse(text, formatter))
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(dates);
```

prints

```
[2016-06-01T15:40, 2016-06-11T11:40]
```

Comment: @YuZhang from Java 6+ you want to be using the new JSR-310 API for parsing and processing Date Time

Answer (score 1):

I went this way using parser.

```
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("11:40 AM 11 Jun 2016", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:m a d MMM yyyy"));
    System.out.println(ldt);
```

If you have multiple white spaces, you can clear input before parsing

```
 String inputDate = "11:40    AM    11   Jun 2016";
 inputDate = inputDate.replaceAll("[ ]+", " ");
```

For multiple dates, move formatter.

```
 //BTW, it is thread-safe.
 private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:m a d MMM yyyy");


 //---
 LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, FORMATTER);
```

Comment: voted up for teaching me how to filter out all space chars. thanks

Comment: Welcome, it is a simple way, but for more complex ways you should get rid of tabs and other characters which look like whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

Convert string dates to `Date` and then add them to a list (collection) and sort them.

**Check out the working example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/viewproject.php?URL=compile_java_online.php&PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMb1hGV3o5ZE1XaG8)!!**

```
    // Your dates to sort
    String dates[] = {"3:40 PM 1 Jun 2016", "11:40 AM 11 Jun 2016"}; 

    List<Date> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    // Your date format
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a dd MMM yyyy"); 

    for(String str : dates){
        //creating the collection of your dates converted to java dates
        lst.add(format.parse(str)); 
    }

    //sorting  the dates
    Collections.sort(lst);

    //converting the dates into new format (if required)
    DateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
    for(Date date : lst){
        System.out.println(newFormat.format(date));
    }
```